# Number of paths in mXn grid

Tags: combinations, permutation, dynamic-programming

Is there a way to find the number of paths in mXn grid moving one cell at a time either downward, right or diagonally down-right using Permutation, starting from (1,1) and reaching (m,n)? I know there is a straight-forward DP solution and also P&C solution (i.e. m+n-2Cn-1) if the movement is only downward and right.

Comment: you should be able to extend the DP approach to include the diagonal condition. `CountPath[i][j] = CountPath[i-1][j] + CountPath[i][j-1] + CountPath[i][j] //Moves diagonally downwards`

Comment: Hopefully my answer is not too late being only three years 

Answer (score 1):

Look up [Delannoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number) numbers. The combinatoric solution is expressed as a sum of multinomials.

Let *t* be the number of diagonal moves, the equation becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This just needs a slight extension to the already existing solution DP solution that computes the path allowing movements only downwards and rightwards.

The only change you need to make is to count the number of ways you can reach a point if you move diagonally as well.

The code I took from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-top-left-bottom-right-nxm-matrix/ should help you understand it better.

```
// Returns count of possible paths to reach cell at row number m and column
// number n from the topmost leftmost cell (cell at 1, 1)
int numberOfPaths(int m, int n)
{
    // Create a 2D table to store results of subproblems
    int count[m][n];

    // Count of paths to reach any cell in first column is 1
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        count[i][0] = 1;

    // Count of paths to reach any cell in first column is 1
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        count[0][j] = 1;

    // Calculate count of paths for other cells in bottom-up manner using
    // the recursive solution
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)

            //               Rightwards      Downwards     Diagnoally right
            count[i][j] = count[i-1][j] + count[i][j-1] + count[i-1][j-1];

    }
    return count[m-1][n-1];
}
```

Comment: I know this DP solution. Is there a way to solve the above problem using Combinatorics ?